# Introducing Punograms

Tags: wordplay, anagram

Match each word in the first list with its punogram in the second.

14 bl see 77 222 68 904 500
bed lips rolo imom him 213

2B LL BG hob peg slip l8r
hi 314 ZZZ 335 wow! 85 PI

Define punogram.

Finally demonstrate your understanding by inventing your own punogram.

Comment: Heya, I've cleaned up the tags a little in my edit - just to let you know why: [tag:open-ended] puzzles are [no longer in scope for this site](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles), and there's no need to create a new tag just yet unless this style really takes off and many more questions along a similar vein get posted by multiple users. Thanks!

Comment: (I notice you've re-edited your question to undo a lot of my presentational edits. While you are completely at liberty to do that, please note that including a challenge for 'the most creative' makes this question open-ended, out of scope for this site, and will likely see it closed as such.)

Comment: You are free not to answer the question. It is labelled open-ended. Why should a majority of people who wish to answer closed questions stop the minority of people who do wish to answer open-ended questions? Should the majority of people who don't do connect-wall questions stop the minority who do? That's what the labels are for. Can you not have your own interests but be more open to minorities? What would be a better place to ask such questions? Having different sorts of puzzles is well within the spirit of the site.

Comment: Please read the linked meta post - the salient points are made there much better than I can hope to achieve in a single comment. Note that these types of questions become a case of subjectivity (and could better be described as 'games' rather than 'puzzles') and they are not a good fit for the remit of this site where the point is to have clear unarguable solutions. A better place to discuss or play them is in The Sphinx's Lair chatroom, which is also a better place than comments to reopen or extend discussion on this topic - please feel free to ask in there :)

Comment: @David, the point Stiv is making is that open ended question is not within the spirit of the site, as described in the linked meta post :)

Comment: Yes, and @Stiv linked to a post that said that there is a consensus. Clearly it is not a consensus as I don't consent. Nor is it a majority vote, as the majority did not vote and were quite happy to live and let live. Clearly there is a well defined answer within the puzzle if that's what you care about.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, a response to the answerer to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

A punogram of a word or number is...

> ...an anagram where its letters or digits (written on a seven-segment display) can be manipulated in some additional 'creative' ways than merely rearranging. Letters/digits can be:
>
>  - converted between letters and digits that have similar seven-segment representations, e.g. 'B' = '8', '2' = 'Z', '5' = 'S', etc.;
>  - split apart to form multiple letters/digits, e.g. 'B' → '1' and '3';
>  - combined to form a single letter/digit, e.g. 'o' and 'o' can be stacked to form an '8' or a 'B';
>  - rotated, e.g. 'w' clockwise by 90 degrees to form a '3', 'i' by 180 degrees to form an exclamation mark;
>  - reflected, e.g. 'b' to 'd'...
>
>  Indeed, even any combination of the above - in short, almost anything goes! If the shapes made by the segments can be rearranged to form another recognisable letter/digit, that's fine. Some letters can even be kept exactly the same while others around them are manipulated.

You can see this in the pairs given in the puzzle:

> Firstly, you can make one match through just a regular anagram:
>
>  lips = slip
>
>  And another by just reading the same seven-representation as letters rather than digits:
>
>  222 = ZZZ
>
>  Then there are several which pair merely by rotating the whole word 180 degrees, as if turning a calculator upside down:
>
>  14 = hi
>  77 = LL
>  bed = peg
>  68 = BG
>  imom = wow!
>  904 = hob
>  see = 335
>
>  You can combine characters to form others:
>
>  213 = 2B (1 and 3 combine to make B)
>  rolo = l8r (o's combine to make 8)
>  500 = 85 (o's combine to make 8)
>
>  And perform multiple manipulations together:
>
>  him = 314 (m turned on side to make 3, h rotated to make 4, i read as 1)
>  bl = PI (reflection and rotation of b to make P, l read as I)

Another example of a punogram is:

> mp3 = wed, involving rotations of the three characters, and rearranging them.